# (C++) How can I test the new application in MOOS-ivp?

Tags: c++, compilation, ros

I've got a problem with compiling my basic code with **MOOS-ivp**. 
I made ***main.cpp***, ***simpleApp.cpp*** and ***simpleApp.h*** from documentation, where should I put it to build it with moos? In docs there is note about launching **MOOSDB** and **uMS** - ok, but there is not any option to find path to my .cpp file. Is there any default path? Maybe should I compile it firstly with gcc?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you know some basic information about MOOS or are taking the MIT 2.680 course and know some of the terminology talked about in the introduction lab.

The recommended way to build external MOOS is to have `moos-ivp` and `moos-ivp-extend` in a directory next to each other. You should run `GenMOOSApp_AppCasting` in the `moos-ivp-extend/src` directory and add your new project to the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the same directory. Then, use the included `./build.sh` script to build your executables, and add the directory it makes to your `$PATH`.

Finally, you should be able to run your mission with your new MOOS app.